# ADT 15.0: XML indentation formatting broken?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, adt

Running Eclipse **3.7.1**.M20110909-1335 with the ADT plugin
Have upgraded from ADT version **12.0.0**.v201106281929-138431 to version **15.0.0**.v201110251216-213216
It looks like that the formatting of XML concerning the indentation size is broken in version 15.
*Window|Preferences|XML|XML Files|Editor* is configured with:

- *Indent using spaces*
- *Indentation size: **2***

Activation of *Source|Format* (*Ctrl+Shift+F*) gives 4 spaces indentation instead of expected 2 spaces
Worked as expected  in previous version 12.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if maybe this is your issue, but under `Preferences > Android > Editors` I have a checkbox (unchecked by default) that says `Use Eclipse setting for indentation width and space or tab character indentation (Android default is 4 space characters)`.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Thanks. XML formatting in Eclipse/ADT always confused me and this was the secret preferences I was looking for.